# Updating packages when network access to standard repositories is blocked

Tags: apt, software-installation, zip, texlive

My college just blocked Ubuntu repositories. So is there any way to install texlive package from something like zip?

I need to run this command,

```
sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-pdf texlive-latex-extra texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended
```

So can anyone provide an alternate way to do the same.

Comment: why not use something like a proxy site to bypass your school

Comment: @TaylorBioniks they have even blocked proxy sites

Comment: If you're going to download those packages using other computer with access to internet and Ubuntu repositories, you can use [Cube](http://launchpad.net/camicricube). Just follow [this guide](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583).

Comment: Go find the idiot who blocked it and kick them.  Ok, don't really do that.  Just go find who is in charge and explain to them why it needs to be unblocked.

Comment: @EliahKagan  I would have thought so, but the accepted answer here provides a solution that works here, but is not applicable there.

Comment: @belacqua he convinced the op to follow the above link.

Comment: [OP still doesn't have a working solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435747/updating-packages-when-network-access-to-standard-repositories-is-blocked/441294?noredirect=1#comment579185_441294)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select different Ubuntu mirror that is not blacklisted in your college.

Change `/etc/apt/sources.list` like here:

```
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

[Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) is the list with plenty of Ubuntu mirrors. Choose what is best for you.

Comment: @ Danatela I tried with several mirrors.It is also not working.

Comment: Then for you is better to use [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Apart of changing repositories (really?), you can use https instead. Just change all entries from http to https:

```
deb https://repository.ubuntu.com saucy main # this is a made up domain
```

You can also use ftp, or rsync.

Comment: I tried this.But Iam getting output as "Ign https://repository.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease "

Comment: @sethulekshmi edit your question instead